# start activity if application is visible

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am implementing session timeouts in my application.
here what i want to do is launch the login activity if and only if the application is visible (i.e. shown) else i don't want to do anything as when the application is laucnced again it will automatically start off with login Activity itself..

```
final List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : tasks) {
        runningactivities.add(0,runningTaskInfo.topActivity.toString());  
    }
```

But this doesn't work for me as it launches the Login Activity in both cases..

Please Help!!
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to read up on the activity life cycle.
You know when you application/activities are visible, when they are not paused. And application is usually not killed even when you leave it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use intent receivers in your activity.  You can register a receiver in the Activity(or activities) that you only want the new activity to be launched from.  Then you can launch the new activity with sendBroadcast(intent).  You should register and unregister you reciever in each activity as shown below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CONSTANT_FOR_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //handle the intent here - launch activity, etc
    }
};
```

Now you can launch your activity with this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CONSTANT_FOR_INTENT);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You can also use sendOrderedBroadcast to set a priority and do something else with the intent if your activity is not running.